# is there a way to do a quick check of the type of a discriminated union value, without using match

Tags: f#

let's say I have this type:

```
type ResultInfo =
| Success
| Error of (HttpStatusCode * string)
```

and a function that returns 'result' of type ResultInfo

is there a way to do something like:

```
if result is type Success then ...
```

because sometimes I just want to know the type and the match syntax can be a bit heavy in cases where you just need to do a quick check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a type test because a union case isn't a real type - it's an union type (like unions in C) with a tag which denotes which case it is.

That's why you cannot do something like this:

```
type MoreSuccess = MoreSuccess of Success //type Success is not defined
```

So you can't do a run-time type check. However, for members which implement structural equality, you can directly compare them. So,

```
if result = Success then
    printfn "Success!"
else
    printfn "Boo"
```

is perfectly valid, and legible as well.
If you really want to use an `if` expression,a more compact way would be define an inline function like this:

```
if (function Error _ -> true | _ -> false) result then
    printfn "Error"
```

Interestingly, the compiler will generate augmented properties like `IsSuccess`, `IsError` which work as expected, however, they're for the benefit of interop with DUs from other languages like C# and VB and are unfortunately not visible in F#.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a helper module like `Option.isSome`

```
module ResultInfo =

    let isSuccess = function
        | Success -> true
        | Error _ -> false

    let isError = function
        | Success -> false
        | Error _ -> true

if result |> ResultInfo.isSuccess then
    ...
```

or attach a property/function to your type

```
type ResultInfo =
    | Success
    | Error of (HttpStatusCode * string)
    member self.IsSuccess =
        match self with
        | Success -> true
        | Error _ -> false

if result.IsSuccess then
    ...
```

I always prefer to specify all union cases explicitly so that by adding a new case will generate a compiler warning. In case you match `Success` only and handle all other union cases with `_` could lead to a potential bug as you get no compiler warning and maybe forget to handle that case.

Comment: So the F# compiler itself generates the `IsSuccess`, `IsError` properties - they're just not accessible in F#. Defining it yourself, like in in your example, will fail to compile unless you disable augmentation.

Comment: just tested this; it's odd that it's not accessible from F#, it would totally make sense!

Comment: I would make the attached a property rather than a function. But I'm nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the string values with a function like this:

```
let sameStrings ut1 ut2 =
    let firstPart (str:string) = str.Split([|' '|])
    let nameString = string >> firstPart
    nameString ut1 = nameString ut2
```

then have an if statement like `if sameStrings Success a then`

Sample usage and output below (Note this won't compare the actual error values, but you should be able to just use a string compare if you wanted to do this):

```
type ResultInfo =
    | Success
    | Error of (int * string)

let printSameAs ut1 ut2 = 
    printfn "%A - match %A: %b" ut1 ut2 (sameStrings ut1 ut2)

let a = Success
let b = Error (404,"Not Found")

printSameAs a Success
printSameAs b Success
printSameAs a (Error (0,""))
printSameAs b (Error (0,""))
```

With output:

```
Success - match Success: true
Error (404, "Not Found") - match Success: false
Success - match Error (0, ""): false
Error (404, "Not Found") - match Error (0, ""): true
```